# Python and Pyramid -reading a ini file in python using configparser

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, configparser

I need to read an ini configuration file in Python and the related sample from the related section of the **development.ini** is below:

```
[app:main]
use = egg:ePRO

pyramid.reload_templates = true
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = true
pyramid.debug_routematch = true
pyramid.debug_templates = true

sqlalchemy.url = postgres://scott:tiger@localhost:5432/db
```

I'm using the `ConfigParser` module to read the file but unable to read the `sqlalchemy.url` parameter from the INI file,

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read(config_uri)
```

How do I read the `sqlalchemy.url` parameter from the `[app:main]`?

Answer (score 5):

As [the documentation shows](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/configparser.html#examples), use the `get` method on your `config` object

```
url = config.get('app:main', 'sqlalchemy.url')
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I found that the following was necessary (a better example by using the Pyramid `bootstrap` features to connect to the SQLAlchemy database follows in the Update section) is added at the bottom of this question, since the **%(here)s** occurs in the url for SQLite in the same folder, so I am adding this answer to this question in the case this is helpful for anyone else, especially since the Pyramid `alchemy` scaffold uses SQLite by default (with this configuration and with the **(here)s**, and the answer above did not work correctly for me with either a `ConfigParser`, or `SafeConfigParser`, instance. I am working with Python 2.7.5 and it looks like this relates specifically to the characters in the `sqlalchemy.url` requiring **raw_mode** by specifying the additional **1** parameter in the `get` command to obtain this value.  The [documentation link](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/configparser.html#examples), also mentioned in the above, includes notes about raw mode. The following is from Python interactive prompt launched in my Pyramid application directly at the same location as my **development.ini** (primarily the 4th row shows the difference):

```
>>> import ConfigParser, os
>>> config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.readfp(open('development.ini'))
>>> config.get('app:main', 'sqlalchemy.url', 1)
'sqlite:///%(here)s/db.sqlite'
```

Also note that the following gives a similar error message to the following command:

```
>>> config.get('app:main', 'sqlalchemy.url', 0)
```

These are results I encountered with Python 2.7.5 when executing the code above is as follows:

```
>>> url = config.get('app:main', 'sqlalchemy.url')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "--python_path--\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 623, in get
    return self._interpolate(section, option, value, d)
  File "--python_path--\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 669, in _interpolate
    option, section, rawval, e.args[0])
ConfigParser.InterpolationMissingOptionError: Bad value substitution:
        section: [app:main]
        option : sqlalchemy.url
        key    : here
        rawval : sqlite:///%(here)s/db.sqlite
```

For a specific reference from the documentation, see the following excerpt which illustrates this more clearly and is far more portable than not using raw mode:

```
# Set the third, optional argument of get to 1 if you wish to use raw mode.
print config.get('Section1', 'foo', 0) # -> "Python is fun!"
print config.get('Section1', 'foo', 1) # -> "%(bar)s is %(baz)s!"
```

**Update - Connect to Pyramid Database And Still Use SQLAlchemy**

The following code has been tested with Pyramid 1.6.1 and uses the `MyModel` class exactly as it comes from the alchemy scaffold with no additions/changes made to the model structure:

```
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config

from pyramidapp.models import (
    DBSession,
    MyModel,
)
from pyramid.paster import bootstrap
env = bootstrap('/path/to/development.ini')
settings = env['registry'].settings
engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
one = DBSession.query(MyModel).first()
print("ID: %i Name: %s Value: %i " % (third.id, third.name, third.value))
```

Sample Output:

```
ID: 1 Name: one Value: 1
```